# How to fix a flaky test when it encounters Object Disabled Exception from time to time?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using watir webdriver and trying to click an external website via my tests. I get 
Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException) intermittently when my automation clicks on a login button. 
Is there an alternative for this ?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but you could try [waiting](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/) to ensure that the element is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @orde mentioned, you could try waiting for the element to become enabled:

```
button = browser.button # Your login button
browser.wait_while { button.disabled? }
browser.button.click
```

Note that you cannot use the Element#when_present method since `present?` does not consider the enabled/disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute force approach but you could monkey patch the click method to rescue the disabled exception, but the wait is probably more appropriate